# JavaScript equivalent to Ruby's .each

Tags: javascript, arrays, each

Does JavaScript have an equivalent to Ruby's `.each` method?

For example Ruby:

```
arr = %w(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
arr.each do |multi|
  sum = multi * 2
  puts "The sum of #{multi} ^ 2 = #{sum}"
end
#<=The sum of 1 ^ 2 = 11
   The sum of 2 ^ 2 = 22
   The sum of 3 ^ 2 = 33
   The sum of 4 ^ 2 = 44
   The sum of 5 ^ 2 = 55
   The sum of 6 ^ 2 = 66
   The sum of 7 ^ 2 = 77
   The sum of 8 ^ 2 = 88
   The sum of 9 ^ 2 = 99
   The sum of 10 ^ 2 = 1010
```

Does JavaScript have an equivalent to something like this?

Comment: @isvforall Can you give me an example of using `foreach`? Is it the same as using the `for` loop?

Comment: Can you look up [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) on the internet? You are expected to do a minimum of research before asking questions on SO. See [ask].

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I actually looked up `javascript equivelent to Rubys.each` before asking, but thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function

```
var arr = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'];
arr.forEach(multi => {
    var sum = multi.repeat(2);
    console.log(`The sum of ${multi} ^ 2 = ${sum}`);
});
```

#### Working example:

```js
var arr = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'];
arr.forEach(multi => {
    var sum = multi.repeat(2);
    document.write(`The sum of ${multi} ^ 2 = ${sum}</br>`);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

An equivalent is

```
myArray.forEach(callback);
```

where `callback` is your callback function. In this case, the function that is going to be executed for each element.

Note that callback can be passed in to ways:

**First:**

```
myArray.forEach(function(element, index, array){
    //Operations
    console.log(element)
});
```

**Second:**

```
function myCallback(element, index, array){
    //Operations
    console.log(element)
}

myArray.forEach(myCallback);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
arr.forEach(function(element,index){
  var sum = element.toString() + element.toString();
  console.log("The sum of "+ element+"^ 2 = "+sum);
});
```